# How to use grep to search for multiple options

Tags: linux, grep

How can I use grep to search for line with either 'res' or 'rep'?

I tried `grep -e res|rep` and `grep -e "rep|rep"` but neither worked.

Answer (score 24):

You can also use `-E` option with `grep`, so there's no need to escape `|`, for example:

```
grep -E 'res|rep' file
```

Or, you can use `egrep`, which is the same thing as `grep -E`:

```
egrep 'res|rep' file
```

Comment: This did not work for me on OS X when I did `pmset -g sched | grep -E "shutdown|restart|sleep"`. (Neither did using `egrep`.)

Answer (score 10):

You need to escape the pipe character:

```
grep 'res\|rep' file
```

or use multiple `-e` options:

```
grep -e 'res' -e 'rep' file
```

Answer (score 1):

- The regex sort of way is:

  **EDIT** `grep -nis "re[sp]" <FILENAME>`
- This way you will be presented with all lines containing either "res" or "rep"
- also note that `-nis` is in no way important here, I just like it that way... :)

Comment: Probably you want to escape `re[sp]` so that it is not accidentally expanded by the shell should there be files named res or rep.

Comment: This is not necessary since it is first after the options list, and as such s interpreted as a pattern.

Comment: hlovdal's comment is correct. The given answer will break if files called 'res' and 'rep' exist, because the shell will convert the command-line into "grep -nis rep res <FILENAME>". Hence you will not find any occurences of 'res' - instead you will search for 'rep' in files 'res' and <FILENAME>.

Comment: Added double quotes to ensure pattern being interpreted well.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple patterns can be specified by using the `-e pattern` or `--regexp=pattern` option instead of specifying the pattern inline.

```shell
grep -e res -e rep
```

or

```shell
grep --regexp=res --regexp=rep
```

Per the Linux [`grep`  man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) (with formatting added):

> `-e PATTERNS`, `--regexp=PATTERNS`
>
> Use `PATTERNS` as the patterns.  If this option is used multiple times […], search for all patterns given.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern string used by `grep` treats the newline character as a pattern separator.  Therefore, using a newline is one way to search for multiple patterns.

```shell
grep $'res\nrep'
```

Per the Linux [`grep`  man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) (with formatting added):

> `grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]`
>
> […]
>
> `grep` searches for `PATTERNS` in each `FILE`.  `PATTERNS` is one or more patterns separated by newline characters, and grep prints each line that matches a pattern.